# Programming DRY or optimize for speed when massive operation?

Tags: php, performance, optimization, dry

I'm trying to figure out if there's ever a situation bypass DRY coding when it could avoid a large query/function.

Essentially, I can calculate a variable every time it's needed (a student's financial balance) or store it as a single variable and update that variable every time a payment is made.  My guess is that even if it's cycling through a thousand payments, it's better to calculate each time to keep it DRY.  But it's more the concept as this situation could arise with database calls or more complex operations that could take a more significant amount of time or processing speed.

Example php code:

```
$payments = array(
    array(
        'plan'  => 100,
        'fees'  => 0.10,
        'paid'  => 110      
    ),array(
        'plan'  => 100,
        'fees'  => 0.05,
        'paid'  => 105  
    ),array(
        'plan'  => 100,
        'fees'  => 0.15,
        'paid'  => 115      
    ),
);

function calculate_balance($payments){
    $max = count($payments);
    $balance = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $balance = ($payments[$i]['plan'] * (1 + $payments[$i]['fees'])) - $payments[$i]['paid'];
    }
    return $balance;
}
// either save balance as a varaible and only adjust when new payment made...
// or calculate the balance every time it's needed
```

Is there ever a situation where I should store a variable rather than calculate it each time?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with calculating it every time is performance, of course.

The problem with just updating a prior result is correctness.
If something happens to make it wrong, you don't necessarily know.

A way to do both is to use the updating method, but once in a while regenerate it from scratch.
In the process, you can tell if the updated value was wrong, and use it to issue a warning to try to find out how it got wrong.

Comment: So in other words, sometimes it is worth bypassing DRY for performance?  Makes sense.  What if the value was updated when performance wasn't an issue, such as via cron, or sometime not during a page load?

Comment: @DavidHobs: Let's back up a bit. Something has redundancy if a single change makes it inconsistent, so whenever you change it, you have to do more than one change in order not to break it. Data structure can have redundancy, and source code can have redundancy. DRY usually refers to source code. In data structure it's called normalizing. You're referring to data structure, and yes sometimes you can bypass it for performance (if you need the performance), but  since you can break the data structure, you should always know how you're going to repair it.

Comment: thanks that helps to clarify and makes a lot of sense.  Especially DRY code v. data structure and normalizing it.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

First, make it work.  It doesn't matter how fast the code is if it doesn't give the right answer.

Then, measure to see how long it's taking.  Is it taking too long?  If not, then you have nothing to optimize.

If you need to speed up the code, then you must measure to find out what parts of your code are taking the longest with a code profiler.  For PHP, use XDebug.